# How to properly reboot pi without disconnecting power

Tags: ssh, shutdown

I have observed that if I use any of the following commands to reboot my RPi 2B:

```
$ sudo reboot
$ sudo shutdown -r now
$ sudo shutdown -Hr now
```

and then try to SSH into the Pi, I get a `Connection Refused` error. It pings normally, though. Then I have to go to the Pi, restart the power supply. Then I can SSH into it normally, after it boots up again.

How do I remotely restart the pi, while maintaining SSH access after it boots?

I didn't have this problem before. I have touched the `/etc/fstab`, the firewall, keep USB drives plugged in it and am running [HAP-NodeJS](https://github.com/KhaosT/HAP-NodeJS) on it currently. This loads up on startup (with `cron`). `pkill`ing it (`node`, not `cron`) before `reboot` doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

P.S. Earlier, even restarting the power wasn't working. It turned out to that a drive in `/etc/fstab` that was set to `auto` was unplugged.

Now, every time I have to reboot it, I have to restart the power supply to use SSH, or start any program.

Comment: This is unanswerable. Rebooting a Pi (I have 6) with `sudo reboot` results in nomal operation. I don't doubt that you have a problem, but it is more likely due to your client, not the Pi.

Comment: By the client, do you mean HAP?

Comment: I don't know what HAP is. I suggest you reboot whatever you are using to `ssh` (the ssh client) into the Pi - only if you have problems worry about the Pi.

Comment: When I **reboot the pi**, I can't `ssh` into it

Comment: During startup you can get `connection refused` before ssh is started. This should be visible easily in the syslog.

Comment: It might hang during shutdown for some reason. Can you hook up a monitor and watch what it does, when you try to `reboot`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't. What do I look for in the syslog?

Comment: Sounds like you've got something hanging in your shutdown or startup as @sborsky suggested. A serial terminal connected to the GPIO RX/TX ports should show you the problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a problem in the /etc/fstab file. It had an entry for `/dev/sda1` (`vfat`). I ran `blkid` and found that the device I wanted to mount was `sdb1` and `sda1` was formatted as `ntfs`. So I changed `fstab` and now everything is back to normal. I can reboot to my heart's content!

Thanks to Glenn for the last nudge to look at the `fstab` file.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the touch command you typed in is causing the problem.  If you used the backstroke '\' in your touch command instead of the forwardstroke '/', you created an empty file in the main directory called 'etcfstab'.  I'm not sure why this stops ssh'ing into the pi but it does.  To fix this problem, power cycle the Pi.  Then you should be able to ssh into the Pi.  Use the 'ls' command to list the files and you should see 'etcfstab' in the list of files.  To remove this file use the command 'rm etcfstab'.  Then reboot and your ssh session should work.  Hopes this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your pointing out, and your help. It made me investigate and I found the source of the problem.